# I want to convert a sound from Mic to binary and match it from the database

Tags: asp.net

I want to convert a sound from Mic to binary and match it from the database(a type of voice identification program but don't getting idea how to get sound from Mic directly so that i can convert it to binary?Also it is possible or not. Please guide me  )

Comment: Do you want to do it in ASP.net? you probably need to write an ActiveX. or some client side control.. as directly in ASP.net you wouldn't be able to do this on client's computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this:

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/4967-How-record-voice-from-microphone.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to be able to identify voices by doing a binary comparison on sound data. The binary of a particular sound will not be identical to an imitation of that sound unless it is literally the same file because of minor variations in just about everything. You'll need to do some signals processing to do a fuzzy comparison of the data.  You can read about signal processing on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_processing).

You will probably find it easier to use a third party library to process the sound for you.  Something like [this](http://biosig.sourceforge.net/) might be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at two very distinct problems here.

The first is pretty technical: Getting sound from the microphone into a digital waveform. How you do this exactly depends on the OS and API you're using (on Windows, you're probably looking at DirectX audio or, if available, ASIO). Typically, this is how you'd proceed:

1. Set up a recording buffer for the microphone, with suitable parameters (number of channels, physical input on the sound card, sample rate, bit depth, buffer size)
2. Start the recording. This usually involves pointing the sound library to a callback function to process the recorded buffer.
3. In the callback, read the buffer, convert it to a suitable format, and append it to the audio file of your choice. (You could also record to RAM only, but longer recordings may exceed available storage).
4. Store the recorded audio in a suitable database field (some kind of binary blob)

This is the easy part though; the harder part is matching a chunk of audio data against other chunks. A naïve approach would be to try and find exact matches, but that won't help you much, because the chance that you find one is practically zero - recording equipment, even the best, introduces a bit of random noise, and recording setups vary slightly whether you want to or not, so even if you'd have someone say something twice, perfectly identical, you'd still see differences in the recorded audio.

What you need to do, then, is find certain typical characteristics of the waveform. Things you could look for are:

- Overall amplitude shape
- Base frequencies
- Selected harmonics (formants)

Extracting these is non-trivial and involves pretty severe math; and then you'll have to condense them into some sort of fingerprint, and find a way to compare them with some fuzziness (so that a near-match is good enough, rather than requiring exact matches). Finding the right parameters and comparison algorithms isn't easy, and it takes a lot of tweaking and testing; your best bet is to go find a library that does this for you.